# How can I configure my webpack so that I can debug my source files instead of the bundled files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

For some reasons, I need to use webpack to package node js source files, but I cannot debug the compiled files because it is too difficult to read. Debugging with console.log is limited. Is there a better way to solve it?

Here is project example:

tree:

```
.
├── dist
├── index.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── router.js
├── webpack.config.js
├── yarn-error.log
└── yarn.lock
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack --config webpack.config.js && node --inspect-brk=9229 ./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@koa/router": "^9.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

index.js:

```js
import Koa from "koa";
const router = require('./router');

// 创建一个Koa对象表示web app本身:
const app = new Koa();

// 对于任何请求，app将调用该异步函数处理请求：
app.use(router.routes())
    .use(router.allowedMethods());

// 在端口3000监听:
app.listen(3000);
console.log('app started at port 3000...');
```

router.js:

```
const Router = require('@koa/router');
const router = new Router();

router.get('/hello', async (ctx, next) => {
    await next();
    ctx.response.type = 'text/html';
    ctx.response.body = '<h1>Hello, koa2!</h1>';
});

module.exports = router;
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    target : "node",
    mode : "development",
    devtool : 'inline-source-map',
    plugins : [
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename : '[name].js.map'
        })
    ]
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "presets": ["env"],
    "comments": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing devtool to source-map in the config should allow you to just debug your source code.